# How can i access evironment variables in present NodeJS from ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, environment-variables

I want to use my `.env` variable presend in my nodejs root folder in reactjs. I tried using `process.env.TEST` but i always get undefined. any solutions?

My folder structure.

```
Project root
 |-client
 |  |- //react project files
 |  |-app.js
 |
 |- //nodejs project files
 |-.env
 |-server.js
```

I want to access my .env variables in app.js and its components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [find-up](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-up) to get your variables in your whole monorepo.

Find here [a bright article](https://medium.com/@dandobusiness/sharing-a-an-environment-file-across-your-mono-repo-ba06af1229ee) on the usage.

Comment: isnt their a way without any package coz i already have too many packages installed

Comment: @DarkForest you can try to create a route and share your env var but it's touchy.